# Parsing an arithmetical calculation that does not have whitespace

Tags: string, parsing, powershell

I'm just about to write a calculator in PowerShell.
The problem is, I have my whole calculation stored in a variable.

This is an example:

```
$test = '123+456'
```

I want the whole variable to split in 3 parts, "123", "+" and "456".

Anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: Is there a space between each part?

Comment: No, was an error. Sorry.

Comment: then is it always a number then a symbol then a number? a single character symbol? or more?

Comment: always a number then a symbol then a number yes. and always one single character symbol

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex [capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). One way to do this would be to use the **match** operator and the $matches variable (note: regex example allows for + and - sign. To add other operators, add them between the brackets):

```
$test = '123+456'
$test -match "(\d+)([+-])(\d+)"

Write-Host "Left operand = $($matches[1])"
Write-Host "Operator = $($matches[2])"
Write-Host "Right operand = $($matches[3])"
```

An alternative is to use the Groups returned from the Match method on the RegEx object:

```
$test = '123+456'
$regEx = [regex]"(\d+)([+-])(\d+)"

$groups = $regEx.Match($test).Groups

Write-Host "Left operand = $($groups[1].Value)"
Write-Host "Operator = $($groups[2].Value)"
Write-Host "Right operand = $($groups[3].Value)"
```

Answer (score 2):

I doubt this answers your question and it is more of an FYI. Depending on what you are doing with your calculations you do not need to carve out the string components.

```
PS D:\temp> $test = '123+456'
Invoke-Expression $test
579
```